# How to list all users with permissions to current site with javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, jsom

I would like to list all users that has been given permission to site, but when I use this;

```
   var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = clientContext.get_web();
   var users = web.get_siteUsers();
   clientContext.load(users);
```

It somehow list all users that is on the whole site collection, and not only those who has permission on current site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve users that has been given permission to *web* site you could utilize the following script:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var assignments = ctx.get_web().get_roleAssignments();
ctx.load(assignments,'Include(Member)'); 
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
        var users = assignments.get_data().map(function(a){
            if(a.get_member().get_principalType() == SP.Utilities.PrincipalType.user)
               return a.get_member();    
        });

        //print results
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
           console.log(users[i].get_title());
        }

     },
     function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message()); 
     });
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get Permission Levels of each users?

Comment: Nevermind, I found that I could use: get_roleDefinitionBindings().getItemAtIndex(0).get_name()